# Mongo eval arguments taken from a list bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash

I am working on a bash script and would like to have a for loop iterate over specific collections in mongo and perform a count. If any of these specific collections is non-zero, then break the loop.

I have initialize this variable inside my script (assume the connection is working):

```
MONGO_EVAL="mongo prod $MONGO_CONN_CONF --quiet --eval"
```

and also a list for specific collections (initialized above, at an early phase in the script):

```
db_collections=(collectionA collectionB collectionC....)
```

Then iterate over a for loop and count the documents on each collection.

```
 for str in ${db_collections[@]}; do
   $MONGO_EVAL 'db.$db_collections.count();'
 done
```

How do I do it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be rather this:

```
db_collections=(collectionA collectionB collectionC....)

for str in ${db_collections[@]}; do
    mongo "$MONGO_CONN_CONF" --quiet --eval "db.${str}.count();"
done
```

or

```
for str in ${db_collections[@]}; do
    mongo "$MONGO_CONN_CONF" --quiet --eval "db.getCollection('${str}').count();"
done
```

or

```
mongo "$MONGO_CONN_CONF" --quiet --eval "for (let c of ['collectionA', 'collectionB', 'collectionC']) db.getCollection(c).count();"
```

Note, you have to use double quotes (`"`), otherwise `${str}` is not replaced by variable value.

Regarding your actual problem "*If any of these specific collections is non-zero, then break the loop*" if could be like this:

```
for (let c of ['collectionA', 'collectionB', 'collectionC']) {
   let count = db.getCollection(c).count();
   if (count > 0) break;
}
```

Bear in mind, this loop actually does nothing, just count and potentially exit. I assume you would also need at least a `print(c)` or something similar.

Comment: Just another question if I may, is it possible to count and use the array list in the same for loop? I mean,        MONGO_EVAL="mongo prod $MONGO_CONN_CONF --quiet --eval"

for str in ${db_collections[@]}; do
  let count= ($MONGO_EVAL "db.${str}.count();")
  if (count > 0) break;
done

Comment: You mix **bash** script and **javaScript** When you use `--eval "xxx"` then `xxx` is a `JavaScript`, anything outside is `bash`.

Comment: I see. So if I use the first solution you suggested, Is there a way to retrieve the count result into a variable? I mean, I don't want to repeat the array values all the time as I use it in multiple places in my script. I want to be able to use my bash array somehow or extract to a js file and pull it from there.  So say I have the following lines (which works): `db_collections=(CollectionA CollectionB CollectionC..)     for str in ${db_collections[@]}; do
  $MONGO_EVAL "db.${str}.count();"
done
`    how do I save the output of the $MONGO_EVAL query? Sorry I'm new to it, tried multiple wa

Comment: Would be `cnt=$( mongo "$MONGO_CONN_CONF" --quiet --eval "db.${str}.count();" )`  or `cnt=\`mongo "$MONGO_CONN_CONF" --quiet --eval "db.${str}.count();"\``  (Syntax `$( )` is more modern than `\`\``) The eval prints the number of documents, to STDOUT and this value will be stored in variable `cnt`